# Using Pandas resample then populating original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking into the market stats based on a close price one week and the open price the next week.  To do this I'm using `resample` in Pandas. In order to give an example I use pandas DataReader below.

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
```

First to get the daily market data:

```
SP = DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo") 
del SP['Adj Close'] 
del SP['Volume'] 

SP.head()

              Open       High         Low       Close
Date                
2010-01-04  1116.560059 1133.869995 1116.560059 1132.989990
2010-01-05  1132.660034 1136.630005 1129.660034 1136.520020
```

Now the `resample` to weekly timeframe:

```
ohlc_dict = {                                                                                                             
'Open':'first',                                                                                                                                                                                                         
'Close': 'last'}
w1_resamp = SP.resample('1w',how=ohlc_dict, closed='left', label='left')
```

This gives me weekly close and open data.  I now highlight the distance between the close last week and the open this week as per the `np.where` statement.

```
w1_resamp['distance'] = np.where(w1_resamp['Open'] < w1_resamp['Close'].shift(),(w1_resamp["Close"].shift() - w1_resamp["Open"]),'np.nan'); 



               Close    Open        distance
Date            
2010-01-03  1144.979980 1116.560059 
2010-01-10  1136.030029 1145.959961 
2010-01-17  1091.760010 1136.030029 
2010-01-24  1073.869995 1092.400024 
2010-01-31  1066.189941 1073.890015 
2010-02-07  1075.510010 1065.510010 0.6799310000001242
2010-02-14  1109.170044 1079.130005 
2010-02-21  1104.489990 1110.000000 
2010-02-28  1138.699951 1105.359985 
2010-03-07  1149.989990 1138.400024 0.29992700000002515
2010-03-14  1159.900024 1148.530029 1.4599610000000212
```

I now want to add a new column to the original data frame SP showing the time and date the gap (as highlighted in `w1_resamp['distance']`) was closed but have no idea how to do this... anyone can help please?

Image added showing desired output in SP data frame as per request in comments:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Might help to see an example of what you want the final dataframe to look like.  You want a column marking when the original weekly open value was met again, after falling over that week?

Comment: What do you mean by "the gap was closed"? Do you mean when `distance` went from non-null to null? Also your `np.where()` should return `np.nan` for the *else* case, not `''`.

Comment: Hi, so to clarify with an example.  If we see that 2010-01-31 weekly close was 1066.18 and open next week was 1065.51 there was a gap of 0.67 as highlighted in the w1_resamp['distance'] column .  I want to create a new column on the SP dataframe highlighting the day when this gap was closed and price moved back to 1066.18.  Ultimately i will be using minute data and will want to capture the time of day but the example above is not granular enough as the source data is daily.

Comment: Image added showing desired SP dataframe output @Jeff L.  Highlighted values correspond with my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow your request around the "Gap Closed" field, however can try this, and see if you can apply it to the index to get your date calculation.

FYI, the it looks like the "how" method is being depricated, and prints a warning to use .apply()

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01","2018-12-31")
columns = ['open','close']
data = np.random.normal(365,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((len(idx),len(columns))), columns = columns,index=idx)
df['high'] = df['open']*(1+np.random.uniform(.05, .20)) #bull market...
func = {
    'open': df['open'].resample('1w').first(),
    'close': df['close'].resample('1w').last(),
    'high': df['high'].resample('1w').max()
}

df_w = pd.DataFrame(func)
df_w['oc_diff'] = df_w['open'] - df_w['close'].shift()
df_w.head(10)

                open     close      high   oc_diff
2018-01-07  0.268054  0.352703  1.186531       NaN
2018-01-14  0.340011  0.907513  1.127548 -0.012693
2018-01-21  0.764949  0.907459  0.915084 -0.142564
2018-01-28  0.346734  0.703151  1.027472 -0.560725
2018-02-04  0.231348  0.960882  0.911420 -0.471803
```